# Pandas.to_csv returns None when printing out instead of a csv-file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, nonetype

I'm trying to create a csv file out of my Dataframe. I'm doing this with the .to_csv() method from pandas. But when I try to print the csv-file in the Terminal there is printed None. Maybe one of you know where the problem is

[image: My code]

[image: Output in the Terminal]

Comment: Without your actual DataFrame, we can't answer this question.

Comment: did you check the csv file? is the file is filled with data or not?

Comment: Why exactly? You can see the forecast_array-Dataframe in the second picture

Comment: `to_csv` is a method to serialize the df object on the disk and doesn't return anything!

Comment: The problem is that csv_file doesn't get created. Or how can I check the csv_file? I'm creating it in a Linux directory, but I have Windows

Comment: You are using a relative path for the output csv file. That means that the csv file will be created in the **process current directory**. Which may not be what you expect ... Try to export to an absolute path, or alternatively print the currect directory (`print(os.getcwd()`)to make sure of what it is

Comment: @SergeBallesta how can I export that to an absolute path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) states, `to_csv` return None if you supply the `path_or_buf` parameter (which you did, it's the first argument). So pandas act as it supposes, there is no problem.

If you want to print the csv (and don't save it) you can:

```py
print(forecast_array.to_csv(sep=';'))
```

Not supplying `path_or_buf' parameter, this will return the csv formatted as a string